# Detox - Test is stuck at device.launchApp in Android

Tags: android, react-native, testing, detox

I am trying to integrate with my existing Android application which has both Native and ReactNative components. I have followed the setup instructions in their README.

The problem seems to be that when I run `detox test -c android.emu.debug` the app launches in the emulator but after some console.log statements, I found out that the test is stuck at this step:
`await device.launchApp`.

Though the app is launching correctly in the emulator, detox does not seem to be able to detect that and move forward.

I can interact with the launched app in my emulator and can navigate through the activities as expected.

I can see warning this message from detox in my terminal:
[Message from Detox in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrSAq.png)

```
detox[3696] WARN:  [DetoxConnection.js/ERROR, #54058] Action dispatched too early, there is no session to use:

HINT: Please report this issue on our GitHub tracker:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues

{
  messageId: -10000,
  type: 'AppWillTerminateWithError',
  params: [Object]
}
```

Here is my test:

```
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log("awaiting launch app");
     await device.launchApp({
      newInstance: true    });
    console.log("done launch app");
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    console.log("Awaiting react native");
    //await device.reloadReactNative();
    console.log("Awaited react native");
  });

  it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('emailTag'))).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean to have the line `//await device.reloadReactNative();` commented out?